# Attaching existing attachment while sending email

Tags: email

From activity history one can send an email. If there are existing attachments attached with the record then is there any way by which while sending mail we could pickup the existing attachments from the record from which email is getting sent. This would prevent user from downloading the attachment to local and then re uploading in order to send it via mail. We can develop one custom page which will use the existing attachments to send emails. But here I am looking for the standard solution if any. Please suggest. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Standard functionality doesn't support this. You can send single email with attachment from apex.

Comment: Ohk..That is what i thought. Going with custom solution now.